# Laravel Mutator to add predefined values into database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mutators

I'm new into Laravel and I'm trying to store the user's company id on a column of the products table each time a user creates a new product. The company's id it's retrieved from the user's session. I'm trying it with Laravel's Mutator:

```
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['company_id'] = session()->get('company.id');
    }
```

But each time I create a new Product the company id stored it's null. Seems like the function it's never executing. Is there any other resource to perform actions like this?

Comment: Try dd(session()->all()) to see if it has anything stored in it

Comment: I did it and returns the company ID but I think the probloem is that on all the process between submiting the form and the datatabase insert the object it's not instanciated. It's a very customized Laravel installationa our models do not extends Model it's another class instead.

Comment: Well that explains it, since the logic isnt that complicated the easiest way is too put it inside your controller, I'm not sure its possible to do it through accessors since you don't have the default Model setup

Comment: I have no access to the controller that receives the form data that's why tryed to implmented into the model also Products can be created from different sides of the web app so I though it would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures) - this will be executed on model creation before saving. Or you can use another events depends on you logic - see docs.

```
class YourModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::creating(function (YourModel $model) {
            $model->company_id = session()->get('company.id');
        });
    }
}
```

Mutators only works when you change mutating field directly:
`$model->first_name = 'new_name'`

And with your code - you will lost "new_name".

Comment: true now works but the function it's not booted() it's boot() not sure if its just a Laravel version thing

Comment: Oh yes, in Laravel 5 it's name is boot, sorry :)\

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the function name is incorrect, since the accessors use "studly" cased name of the column you wish to access, it may be as simple as to change

```
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
```

to

```
public function setCompanyIdAttribute($value)
```